# Unlock MAC Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript

I want to unlock mac programmatically. Currently i am using Apple script for this propose. And it is working all fine but The issue is it is time consuming process. It take around 4-5 seconds to execute the script. Here is the script i am execution using NSAppleScript. Please suggest me how can i make it work fast. or Any other fastest possible way. Thanks

```
tell me to activate\n
tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"PASSWORD\"\n 
tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke return\n 
tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke return"
```

Comment: "I want to unlock mac programmatically." -- Why?

Comment: There's really no sense in locking it if you're placing plain text passwords in your code.

Comment: Is it the script that's slow? Not login?  You might be able to speed things up with no state restoration, if that's possible.

Comment: @I'L'I PASSWORD is there as a placeholder.

Comment: @stevesliva I have observed the process. Its actually the script that took long time. Might be possible script is ok and process is slowing up because computer is waking up. But what i want to know is any possible fastest way to do this task. Or to improve the process i am using.

Comment: @Saani did you find any solution .please let me know if you have resolved it actually i am facing the same situation. in one of my app. please post the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell security preferences
       set require password to wake to false
    end tell
 end tell

tell application "System Events"
    stop current screen saver
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell security preferences
        set require password to wake to true
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: When i lock my Mac and try to unlock with the given script, it doesn't do anything moreover my Mac also asks for username and password both. In System prefereces>Security&Privacy i have the disable automatic login unchecked.

Comment: I think root rights are required to execute thiis script?